# Values are not displaying in table view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have declared an array in ViewController and displaying it in table view. I am passing values for an array from EditViewController. But the values are not displaying in table view. I am using following code.

ViewController.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;
```

ViewController.m

ViewDidLoad:

```
   tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",nil];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
}
```

EditViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  ViewController *vc;
  vc = [segue destinationViewController];    
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", selectedRow];
  [vc.tableData addObject:str];
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: See whether Delegate and Datasource connected for the tableview

Comment: Delegate and Datasource both are connected. But cellforrowatindexpath not called.

Comment: Set breakpoint in Cellforindexpathrow and see whether app getting triggered there.

Comment: So i think its not connected properly check your table delegate connection. Is it iBOutlet or programaticlly created Table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plz make sure you have

```
-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

method defined. This method should return value greater than **0** so that

`-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

gets called.

Comment: Yes, initially it was 0. But in editviewcontroller i am adding value to it.still it not calling.

Comment: What does the **-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** method return. and in your **-viewDidLoad** check tableData values.

Comment: tableData value is 0.

Comment: Got it that is the main problem here. It means your tableData has no values. Just to verify you can dump some temporary data and check if the **-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method gets called make sure you return [self.tableData count] from **-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:**. Once that is done you can figure out why tableData is not getting populated.

Comment: i set empty value and it enters in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then the tableData count value is 1.But after passing value in editviewcontroller  tableData becomes 0.

Comment: Move `tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",nil];` to `-initWithCoder`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no data in the tableview itself, hit a breakpoint at

```
 cellForRowAtIndexPath,
```

and Still if it dsnt hits the breakpoint,connect the Delegate and Data source for the tableview with the View Controller.

[EDIT]
If it is still not called, go to storyboard, check if the bounds of the tableview, is more than that of the vc, that means, check if the tableview is inside the view controller and no part of the tableview is crossing the bounds of the view controller.

Comment: Delegate and Datasource both are connected. But cellforrowatindexpath not called.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the delegate and datasource to self in the viewDidLOad of editViewController

```
    tableView.delegete=self;
    tableView.Datasource=self;
```

Comment: Delegate and Datasource both are connected. But cellforrowatindexpath not called.

Comment: Have you created the tableview by code or is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: delete that outlet and create a new one.Right click on the tableView and see if any other connections are present.By the time also try to display the tableData at the viewdidload of editViewController.

Comment: try         [self.tableView reloadData]; from the viewdidLoad and using breakpoint ,try if the control reaches the cellforRow method

Answer (score 0):

you are add string to nsarray object which is not allocated.
you have to create nssarray with string and pass to the vc.tableData.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few problems with this.

First, it's best to set a the NSMutableArray property "tableData" to an existing array passed in during the segue. Right now you're adding a single string to a mutable array which, unless you wrote a custom initializer for the ViewController in which you alloc-init'ed the NSMutableArray, it can't exist until ViewDidLoad which is after the segue is performed, so you're passing the string to black abyss of "nil".

It's best to use base types as receiving properties in prepareForSegue, and then in your case to pass the ViewController's array an already existing array from the EditViewController.

Also, you may not be telling the view controller how many cells to actually create. Make sure numberOfSectionsInTableView returns a value (in this case just 1), and that numberOfRowsInSection returns "[self.tableData count]".

And if you didn't create ViewController as inheriting from UITableViewController, you'll need to set that, and connect the delegate and datasource manually in the storyboard like Light Yagami pointed out. Though it would probably be easier to just create a new custom class file that inherits from UITableViewController because it will give you some good boilerplate code.

And also make sure that in your storyboard, your TableViewController's class is set to your custom class file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you did not pass numberOfSectionsInTableView as 0. Please check that once. It must be 1 or more based on requirement. And same for numberOfRowsInSection.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove this line from your `ViewDidLoad` Method

```
tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",nil];
```